# ASP.NET Core 6 AddMicrosoftGraph

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Identity to authenticate an ASP.NET Core 6 application using AAD and this works fine. I want to add in access to Microsoft Graph and added the changed the authentication to:

```
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
       .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
       .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

which seems to be what many people suggest. `DownstreamApi` is in `appsettings.json` and contains the `BaseUrl` and `Scopes` set to `user.read`.

However, despite trying lots of variations I always gets the following error. Can anyone help, please?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
> InvalidOperationException: Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.CreateInstance(Type type)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.GetPropertyValu e(PropertyInfo property, object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindProperty(PropertyInfo property, object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindNonScalar(IConfiguration configuration, object instance, BinderOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.BindInstance(Type type, object instance, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Bind(IConfiguration configuration, object instance, Action configureOptions)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Bind(IConfiguration configuration, object instance)
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderWithConfiguration.
>
> b__1_0(ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions.Configure(string name, TOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string name)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()
> System.Lazy.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
> System.Lazy.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
> System.Lazy.CreateValue()
> System.Lazy.get_Value()
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache.GetOrAdd(string name, Func createOptions)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor.Get(string name)
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.
>
> b__0(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IMergedOptionsStore mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor ccaOptionsMonitor, IOptions ccaOptions)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions, TDep1, TDep2, TDep3>.Configure(string name, TOptions options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string name)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor+ <>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()
> System.Lazy.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
> System.Lazy.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
> System.Lazy.CreateValue()
> System.Lazy.get_Value()
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache.GetOrAdd(string name, Func createOptions)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor.Get(string name)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, string authenticationScheme)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Tried various combinations of the above code but always get the same error. The app is registered in Azure and has Microsoft Graph added

```json
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "AAA",
    "ClientId": "BBB",
    "TenantId": "CCC",
    "ClientSecret": "DDD",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc",
    "RedirectUri": [
      "https://localhost:7069",
      "https://localhost:7069/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7069/Home/Index"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share appsettings.json? According to the stack trace, the issue will be with some parameter inside appsettings.json

Comment: `{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "AAA",
    "ClientId": "BBB",
    "TenantId": "CCC",
    "ClientSecret": "DDD",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc",
    "RedirectUri": [
      "https://localhost:7069",
      "https://localhost:7069/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7069/Home/Index"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read"
  },
  ...
}`

Comment: Could you share your full program.cs file and how you are calling graph endpoint can you share that as well?

Comment: The error suggests there is an issue reading the settings file. Are you successfully calling `builder.Configuration.GetSection()` elsewhere at startup?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur  Right you are. I am assuming so he might be missing reading appsettings value in correct way and that part has not been shared.

Comment: could you pls  try to remove `"RedirectUri": [
      "https://localhost:7069",
      "https://localhost:7069/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7069/Home/Index"` and test again?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Microsoft Identity to authenticate an ASP.NET Core 6
> application using AAD and this works fine. I want to add in access to
> Microsoft Graph and added the changed the authentication to.

Actually, it would be nicer if you would have shared few other configuration as well because the exception you are getting is not related which you have shared here but it might be something while reading the value or building any inastances.

However, as per your description as you saying if have tried so many ways can still cannot make it work. Therefore, I am showing you a great alternative way to create a new one which will definately work out.

Furthermore, before proceeding check your existing app and azure active directory portal  configuration as following which is minimal required configuration you need:

Azure Active Directory Portal:

Make sure you have this configuration with no difference:

[image]

**Note:** Here redirect URI you send  from your application in the request to the login server should match one listed above. For instancee: https://localhost:44359/signin-oidc

appsetting.json:

[image]

appsetting.json should be matchd with above information.

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "yourDomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

//Required Service For Calling Graph API With Azure Ad
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
            .AddDownstreamWebApi("DownstreamApi", builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
//For popping Up Login Prompt
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
                     GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var users = await _graphServiceClient
                   .Me
                   .Request()
                   .GetAsync()
                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
        var getNameFromGraph = users.DisplayName;
        var surname = users.Surname;
        @ViewData["GraphApiResult"] = getNameFromGraph;
        return View();
    }

   
}
```

Note: Make sur you have same configuration as above. If you think its same and do not include any additional feature at this time. You can add them later on.  Now, run the application if you still having that exception, please try the alternative way below.

**Alternative way:**

Pre-requisite:

To test using alternative way, you need to create a new app from visual studio. I am using using visual studio 2022 build version 17.3.6.

Step: 1:

[image]

Step: 2:

[image]

Step: 3:

[image]

Step: 4:

[image]

Step: 5:

[image]

Step: 6:

**Note:** It will load all required dependency autometically. Once its done please check the configuration above I described are same. Afterwards, you are ready to run your app. You can replace controller code I shared to check if the graph API is calling the endpoint accordingly.

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you still have any concern and would like to know more details about the configuration you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#microsoft-libraries-supporting-web-apps)

Comment: Many thanks; this has got me passed the original problem. One thing I note is that when I create the project using the dotnet msidentity tool, appsettings.json contains the section "MicrosoftGraph", however, in the controller you use DownstreamApi - should this be MicrosoftGraph? Aloso, the application works fine for scope user.read, but if I add anything else (eg. "profile" or "team.readbasic.all" I get an error "MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application" yet I have these permissions in Azure Portal?

Comment: Tough its a different contex; thus, Include those scope in your appsetting.json by comma seperated value and make sure you have right permission on azure portal as well.